# adding node at last in Linked List in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have tried to implement Singly Linked List. My addAtLast() function is not getting executed properly. Program crashes while executing this function. Kindly suggest some changes.

```
class LList
{
public:
    int noOfNodes;
    Node const *start;/*Header Node*/

    LList()
    {
        start=new Node;
        noOfNodes=0;start=0;
    }

    void addAtFront(Node* n)
    {
        /*
        cout<<endl<<"class"<<n;
        cout<<"start"<<start;
        cout<<"data in node";n->print();
        */
        n->next=const_cast<Node*>(start);
        start=n;
        // cout<<" next=";start->print();
        noOfNodes++;
    }

    void addAtLast(Node* n)
    {
        Node *cur=const_cast<Node*>(start);
        if (start==NULL)
        { 
            start=n;
            return;
        }
        while(cur->next!=NULL)
        {
            cur=cur->next;
        }
        cur->next=n;
        noOfNodes++;
    }

    int getPosition(Node data)
    {
        int pos=0;
        Node *cur=const_cast<Node*>(start);
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            pos++;
            if(*cur==data)
            {
                return pos;
            }
            cur=cur->next;
        }
        return -1;//not found
    }

    Node getNode(int pos)
    {
        if(pos<1)
            return -1;// not a valid position
        else if(pos>noOfNodes)
            return -1; // not a valid position

        Node *cur=const_cast<Node*>(start);
        int curPos=0;
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            if(++curPos==pos)
                return *cur;
            cur=cur->next;
        }
    }

    void traverse()
    {
        Node *cur=const_cast<Node*>(start);
        while(cur!=NULL)
        {
            //   cout<<"start"<<start;        
            cur->print();
            cur=cur->next;
        }
    }  

    ~LList()
    {
        delete start;
    }
};
```

Comment: Unless you show us how is that function implemented and how it is called, it will be quite difficult to help you.

Comment: "Program crashes" what it is mean?

Comment: Not your problem, but note that `noOfNodes` is not maintained properly - after inserting the first element (when `start==NULL`) you forgot to increase it.

Comment: Show use example where crash occurs.

Comment: What does the `Node` class look like?

Comment: I *suggest* you post a minimal complete example.

Comment: Code has lots and lots of bugs in it. So need to see how you are calling your class methods, perfectly possible that you have bugs in the way you call the methods too. Also has many design issues, I would suggest a rewrite, but if you don't want to do that, then at least post complete code.

Comment: For everyone that is assuming the silver-bullet to this question is to ensure the node *passed in* must have its followup-link set to NULL, (a) it is highly likely you are correct it will solve the issue for this question, and (b) you will utterly destroy any hope of this function chaining two multi-node links together. The **caller** needs to ensure that link is set to null; not this code. (but the OP may not be aware of that).

Comment: I am asking for the suggestions please be specific @john

Comment: A specific suggestion: use a good compiler (like g++) and don't try to add functionality (like `addAtLast()`) until your code compiles (with no warnings) and runs (without crashing) and passes tests (you should test every function you have put in).

Comment: only failing function is adatlast

Comment: Then show us the line where it crashes. We are not sensitives here to know where your program falls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned this in-comment, but will address it here as an answer. The *caller* of this function must ensure two things:

1. That the passed-in node list (and it *is* a list, even if only one element long) **must** be properly terminated with an end-next-pointer set to NULL. The *caller* must ensure this, as this code cannot assume it and blindly set `node->next = NULL;`
2. Make absolutely sure the *caller* is aware that once this executes, **this list now owns the passed-in node and any list it potentially starts** and the caller, therefore, must **NOT** free it, or anything it points to, on the caller side.

Apart from the node-count management issue, there is nothing wrong with the `addAtLast()` function, though I would have implemented it a little differently:

```
void addAtLast(Node* n)
{
    // no nulls allowed
    if (n == NULL)
        return;

    // set start if first in list
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = n;
        noOfNodes = 1;
    }

    // else walk list to find end
    else
    {
        Node *cur = const_cast<Node*>(start);
        while(cur->next != NULL)
            cur = cur->next;
        cur->next = n;
        ++noOfNodes;
    }

    // adjust count to contain any nodes from 'n'
    while (n->next != NULL)
    {
        ++noOfnodes;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is perfect answer @WhozCraig..!!

Comment: @Mohit_Sehgal very glad it helped. Now go check your callers and make sure they're setting their next-pointers correctly  =P

Comment: Sir I want to ask that Why should addAtLast Function must ensure that next pointer is set to NULL even though I had set it NULL in constructor of Node class. @WhozCraig

Comment: @Mohit_Sehgal Perhaps I didn't phrase the answer quite well enough. the point is addAtLast must **assume** the caller has the node properly terminate (next=NULL). **It cannot blindly set it to NULL**. Note the answer code in the sample above does NOT set any next pointers to NULL. It relies on the caller to do that (as it should).  Several of the other answers posted here take the leap of faith that they can safely set `n->next = NULL`. My premise is you cannot do that. You *must* rely on the caller to do that for you (and judging by your comment above, you do, which is a *good* thing).

Answer (score 2):

```
void addAtLast(Node* n) {
    Node *cur=const_cast<Node*>(start);
    if(start==NULL) {
        start=n;
        n->next = NULL;
        noOfNodes++;
        return;
    }
    while(cur->next!=NULL) {
        cur=cur->next;
    }
    cur->next=n;
    n->next = NULL;  // Added
    noOfNodes++;
}
```

Comment: As it's hard to edit the source code, I format it with astyle.

Comment: I had also done the same n->next = NULL; this step is already included in constructor of Node.

Answer (score 1):

From the beginning..

```
start=new Node;
noOfNodes=0;start=0;
```

Should this be?

```
start=new Node;
noOfNodes=0;start->next=NULL;
```

Within 2 lines you've created memory leak. I have no idea why you would want to set `start=0`. Don't do that, you've just assigned memory to it!

As for the crash, it's addressed by @liulinhuai's answer. You'll be dereferencing a pointer that is uninitialized attempting to get it's `next` member.

Comment: This is not a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), it is a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).. I don't think it should cause a crash.

Comment: according to this line: if(start==NULL) { start=n;return;} it is not a problem

Comment: Yes, it's a leak. I've made changes. I didn't say it would cause a crash, and it is still a problem.

Comment: It is probably the source of the crash, unless `Node` ensures that `next == 0` when it is created. And I would not bet on that.

Answer (score 1):

In your ctor you set start as 0. In your crash function you first check it for `NULL`:

```
if (start==NULL)
{ 
   start=n;
   //n->next is now points to nowhere
   return;
}
```

Next call to `addAtLast` iterate until it finds `NULL` but previous assign didnt set `next` pointer to `NULL` so second iteration will cause an `access violation`:

```
while(cur->next!=NULL) {
   //first time it's ok but second call on cur will crash
   cur=cur->next;
}
```

Solution is - all new `Node`'s must have `next` pointer setted to `NULL`

Comment: I have already done that in Node class constructor. n.next is always null when Node is created